# How do I email the contents of a completed form?

Tags: forms, email, anchor

I have created a form that will fill in blanks based on the contents of dropdown menus. As you change the content of the dropdowns the a paragraph fills in the variables. Now, I would like to be able generate an email that prefills the body with the completed paragraph.

Currently the Paragraph is under the following tags:

```
<body id="emailcontent">
        <form method="post">
```

and this is the lines I have tried to create the email:

```
 <a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=Visit" Body="emailcontent" "btn btn--contact">Generate Email</a>

 <a href="mailto:nestess@hoodindustries.com?subject=Mill Visit" Body="post" "btn btn--contact">Generate Email</a>
```